# How to enter grafical root

Tags: files, root

I wanted to paste some files to ***usr/bin/*** that's like a lot of files so I cant copy them by the terminal. So how can I paste them??? How to enter root by there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root privileges to access directories like **/usr/bin**.

If you want to run commands as root you can type:

```
sudo su
```

and then your next commands will be run with root privileges.

You can also type `sudo` and individual commands to run only those commands as root.

If you want to copy files with your file explorer, run your file explorer as root; if you are using Ubuntu type:

```
sudo nautilus
```

If you are using another flavour where Nautilus is not the default file manager, type it's command after the `sudo` (for example: `sudo caja` for MATE).

Comment: God thank u soooo much!